# Crash "DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION" Windows 10 - caused by touchpad

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

**Touchpad** is causing Windows 10 to crash.

Touching the touchpad causes a crash and reboot. It give a "DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION". The problem looks to be 
the  "Synaptics Mouse Driver"

Notes:
Windows 10 Build 10240

Answer (score 1):

**Rollback the driver**

Rolling back worked better than uninstalling. As it did not try to re-install the broken driver via auto updates.

- Open "Device Manager"
- Find and Double click on "Synaptic Touch Pad"
- On General Tab click "Change settings"
- On Driver tab click "Roll Back Driver"

More details: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/synaptics-mouse-driver-update-causes-computer-to/914b748f-b8ca-474e-973c-e63065ef1618?page=4&tm=1441161135932#LastReply

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: @DragonLord it looks to be a moving target. I have added instructions that match my build, but the MS instructions are for older (and I assume outdated) build.